# how to make sure that the node.js calls to mongodb are really asynchronous

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to write a node.js application, and we need to deploy it in production.

We need to make sure that node.js does not hang when there are any long running processes/operations, like querying, or the database server access.

So, i am trying to make a call to mongo or to filesystem which takes very long time to finish,  so that i can verify that other node.js server is free to serve any other requests while that takes place.

Sadly, i am not able to insert a record for which mongo takes really long time to finish or to make a synch call to the file system.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Thanks

Tuco

Comment: They are asynchronous, since they go over the network and async is the only way to do that in node.js.

Comment: I need to be sure that there will not be any long running process that will choke the app. Since its essentially single threaded(even if we make use of the cluster, which makes it n threaded where n is not large)

Comment: The node process is not single threaded.  Node.js user-code (JavaScript) is single threaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is do a console log of the data after the block that do a call and a console.log in the callback if in the console apears first the message is actually asynchronous

Im using mongojs as driver for mongo:

```
collection.find({}, function(err, res) {
    console.log("done")
});
console.log("sendign signal")
```

If its asynchronous, in the console:

```
sendign signal
done!
```

Now for the  chained behavior you can make something like that

```
dbChain = (function() {
  var chain = [], cursor = 0, busy = false;

  chainin = {
    push : function(aFn) {
      if(!busy) {
        chainin.reset();
        aFn();
        busy = true;
      } else {
        chain.push(aFn)
      }
    },

    next : function() {
      cursor++;
      if(chain[cursor]) {
        chain[cursor]();
      } else {
        chainin.reset();
      }

    },

    reset : function() {
      chain = [];
      cursor = 0;
      busy = false;
    }
  }

  return chainin;

})()
```

and, in all the db calls you have to do:

```
dbChain.push(...(a function ) ...)
```

in all your callbacks

```
dbChain.next()
```